# Implementing a simple Theme Switcher in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

[This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMOe_32M6ss) shows how to make an easy Dark/Light theme switcher with Tailwind CSS.  It’s done in vanilla JS with a single app.js file.

So if I wanted to implement this in a Vue project, would I just dump that code into ~/src/main.js, or is there a better way?

Comment: Probably a better way because of Vue's ability to use reactive state. Also, having it as a component, wrapper or alike is probably a good approach for re-usability if needed in several places.

Comment: to be honest, theme should be tri-state ... dark, light, follow-system ... in that tutorial, once you select light or dark, there's no way to go back to "follow-system" - following the system theme is good for people that may like light mode during the day, and switch to dark mode at night for instance - so, while that tutorial is OK, it doesn't handle a use case that is legitimate and fairly common (in my experience - which is why I had to implement it in a vue app)

Answer (score 1):

A good way to implement theme switchers in Vue, is by holding a value in some kind of store like [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) or [pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/).

You could e. g. add a variable isDarkMode (boolean) or pageTheme (string) and depending on its value you can set a different class in your body or individual components, simply by getting the value from store.
Then you could build a theme switcher, which mutates the theme variable on click. ;)

This would be a project-wide option, also with the possibility, to change specific parts.